# Vue router-link: sibling or child relative links

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm working on a web application using Vue 2 as the framework and the accompanying [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) for routing purposes.

I'm developing a kind of tabbed view, so my current approach is to define child routes for my main component. Something along the lines of:

```
{ path: '/user/:id', component: User, children: [
    { path: '', component: UserHome },
    { path: 'profile', component: UserProfile },
    { path: 'posts', component: UserPosts }
]}
```

The setup is OK and routing works as expected. I'm now looking into defining links from the `User` component's template to its **children** (the tabbed navigation). I'm also looking to define a link from the `UserHome` component directly to its **sibling** components (`UserProfile`& `UserDetails`).

As far as I can tell there's no easy way to avoid repeating the full path in the `to`attribute of the `router-link` component to avoid breaking the navigation, see [this working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmxtamj4/) & [this broken Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sj4orqz/) and notice the values of the `to` attributes. I would expect to be able to define a relative path as the value of the `to` attribute to navigate between child and/or sibling paths.

Does anyone know if there's a better way to avoid repeating full navigation paths in a `router-link` component?

Comment: Did you try to name your routes? https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html

Comment: @Traxo I dont think this helps in resolving relative links like in this example (?)

Comment: @phil294 Edit: yes it does

Comment: use append in <router-link to='target' append>text</router-link>, for more: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/index.html#removal-of-append-prop-in-router-link